# inserting number into oracle sql - using jython

Tags: sql, jython

I have this insert command where iam trying to insert a number to be taken from loop

```
i=0
for line in column:
    myStmt.executeQuery("INSERT INTO REVERSE_COL
( TABLE_NAME,COL_NAME,POS) values 
(,'test','"+column[i]+"','"+i+"'")
i=i+1
```

POS IS  NUMBER  DATATYPE

but it works if i hard code as 1

```
i=0
for line in column:
    myStmt.executeQuery("INSERT INTO REVERSE_COL
( TABLE_NAME,COL_NAME,POS) values 
(,'test','"+column[i]+"',1")
```

I have tried only i , +i+ and other method but its not working any suggestion how to solve this .

Thanks everyone .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no jython experience, but I will still try to offer my personal approach and advice. Take from it what you will.

The first thing that I would look into, and perhaps this is something someone else knows offhand, is the way that a number is concatenated to the string. I'm speaking from a C++ background here, but a number `i` may well be converted to the ASCII character representing that value, and not necessarily the character that you intend.

For example, if `i` is 9, it may be placing a `TAB` into the string and not the number `9`, which would be an ASCII value 57.

Again, I'm not telling you this **IS** the answer...but it's the first thing that pops into my mind. Good luck!

Comment: I had a minute during lunch to look around a bit, and I believe this is likely the case. You didn't mention if the "not working" involved receiving an error, or simply invalid data. But I'm guessing it's the former. Please see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Variables_and_Strings#Combining_Numbers_and_Strings for information

You may need to use the `str()` function.

Comment: Keven, 
The error was related to Invalid number since  the target column has a datatype of number and i have specified in the question too moroever over when using +i+ is being in string  and i have tried int(str(+i+) too  but nothing seems to work

Comment: By using `int()` around your `str()` you're effectively *cancelling* the function's result. You're converting it from a number, to a string, and back into a number. It seems from here that you specifically need to use `... + column[i] + "','" + str(i) + "'")` at the end of your query.

Comment: awesome thanks it worked. I was just with the impression that since my target column is number how will str() will go , i was wrong. Thanks for your help